# why use " as this " in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

"That's beautiful," said Annie. Jack smiled. He agreed.

Brother Patrick turned to them. "it is such sights as this that inspire our book-making," he said.

what function is "as this" in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It is a generalizing construction. The meaning is

> It is this sight, and others quite similar to this one,  that …

Obviously, it is far more concise to say

> It is such sights as this that …

My feeling is that

> It is sights such as this that …

is more common in American speech.